# Django OperationalError(2013, "Lost connection to MySQL server during query")

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, amazon-aurora

I've been getting the above error when using two servers to connect to the same Aurora DB.

We're running a simple [Django REST Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) on Elastic Beanstalk which connects to an Aurora DB cluster.  Whenever we start up the DB and test the API from the EBS server connections go through fine.  However, if I then start up my local development server connecting to the same DB, I get the operational error when going to the same route on the local server.

- I've tried increasing 'connect_time', 'interactive_timeout', 'max_execution_time', 'wait_timeout', 'max_allowed_packet', 
  and 'max_user_connections' in increments up to the max.  No change.
- The query shouldn't be big as there's only about 20 items in the table, and most of the time we're querying one item.
- We aren't managing the connection manually anywhere so it's not that we accidentally closed the connection prematurely.
- I've dug through the MySQL logs and only found the following message:

  > Aborted connection ## to db: 'db_name' user: 'username' host: 'host_ip' (Got an error reading communication packets).  Which seems to be pretty generic, and implies something on the dev server is closing the connection.
- The only way to get the development server to stop throwing this exception is to reboot the Aurora DB.
- Django Database settings have the CONN_MAX_AGE set to 0 which makes the most sense to me.
- I created a new Aurora DB instance with fresh migrations and one entry in the table, with the same issues.

In addition if I open the Django shell and run a simple query with the models, the Beanstalk server will then start throwing InterfaceError(0, '').  Again this remains until the Aurora DB is rebooted.

I've dug through a number of sources but haven't found a fix yet.  Anyone else have some ideas?

Version Info

- Django == 2.1.5
- Django REST Framework == 3.9.1
- MySQL Compatibility Engine == 5.7.12

Comment: Might be time for Aurora support.

Comment: 5.7.12 is a bit old isn't it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try use the MySQL connector PyMySQL==0.7.9

Comment: No, I don't. I always use PyMySQL. Never use the another one